# Wordpress - как получить url до папки с темой

Tags: wordpress

WordPress не может найти файл `style.css` и другие. В индексе путь указан как `css/style.css`. В чём проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может будет кому полезно. Решил проблему путём добавления этого кода в каждую ссылку/картинку

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```